# Compiler Looking for .CPP file when the Implementation is Entirely in My .HPP File

Tags: c++, header-files

it looks like my compiler is looking for a corresponding CPP file to my rectangle.h file. I have my entire implementation in the .h file and I don't want to make a CPP file to correspond. As a result, my compiler is throwing the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccywfYT2.o: in function `Sprite::Sprite()':
main.cpp:(.text+0x8a2): undefined reference to `Rectangle::Rectangle()'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccywfYT2.o: in function 
`Sprite::Sprite(Graphics&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, 
std::allocator<char> > const&, int, int, int, int, float, float)':
main.cpp:(.text+0x919): undefined reference to `Rectangle::Rectangle()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

For instance, I have my Rectangle class in rectangle.h

```
#ifndef RECTANGLE_H
#define RECTANGLE_H

#include "globals.h"

class Rectangle {
    private:

        int _x, _y, _width, _height;

    public:

        Rectangle();
        Rectangle(int x, int y, int width, int height) : _x(x), _y(y), _width(width), _height(height) 
{};

        const int inline getCenterX() const {return this->_x + this->_width / 2;};
        const int inline getCenterY() const {return this->_y + this->_height / 2;};

        const int inline getLeft() const {return this->_x;};
        const int inline getRight() const {return this->_x + this->_width;};
        const int inline getTop() const {return this->_y;};
        const int inline getBottom() const {return this->_y + this->_height;};

        const int inline getWidth() const {return this->_width;};
        const int inline getHeight() const {return this->_height;};

        const int inline getSide(const ourSides::Side side) const {
                return  side == ourSides::TOP ? this->getBottom() : 
                        side == ourSides::BOTTOM ? this->getTop() : 
                        side == ourSides::LEFT ? this->getRight() :
                        side == ourSides::RIGHT ? this->getLeft() :
                        ourSides::NONE;
        }

        /* bool collidesWith
         * Takes in another rectangle and checks if the two are colliding.
         * Will be applied to Quote as he moves around. (Quote is in a rectangle)
         */ 

        const bool inline collidesWith(const Rectangle& otherRect) const {
            return 
                    this->getRight() >= otherRect.getLeft() &&
                    this->getLeft() <= otherRect.getRight() && 
                    this->getTop() <= otherRect.getBottom() &&
                    this->getBottom() >= otherRect.getTop();
        }

        const bool inline isValidRectangle() const {
            return this->_x >= 0 && this->_y >= 0 && this->_width >= 0 && this->_height >= 0;
        }

};

#endif // RECTANGLE_H
```

How can I get my program to compile without needing an accompanying CPP file, if that is even my issue.

Comment: The error is right there. `Rectangle();` has no body, and *is* being referenced in your code. Look at your header. A quick way to see what is using that thing is frankly to delete it (i.e. delete `Rectangle();` from the class decl). Whatever that breaks is what is requiring it, and you then see why not providing that implementation causes the problem you're having.

Comment: @WhozCraig Oh man... I forget to add the {}; It's working fine now. Thanks.

Comment: Unrelated: `#include "globals.h"` begs the question do you really need globals? Usually global variables and god headers lead to problems.

Comment: The default constructor that the error message complains about is not defined in your code. Only declared.

Comment: @TomerTzadok Don't use empty brackets for constructor definition if you can use `= default`:  `Rectangle() = default;`

Comment: @KaenbyouRin I've made it default, as you're suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually implement `Rectangle()`. You put a `;` after it, which makes it a declaration.

If you intend to make the constructor blank, instead use `Rectangle() = default;`--unless you're on like a really old compiler that doesn't support this for some reason. Then use `{}` instead of the `;`.